# Solution filters missing from recent projects and solutions in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio

We have started to adopt the Visual Studio filtered solutions. We created 1 big solution (1200 projects) and about 100 solution filters.

We are experiencing inconsistent behaviour. In most of the cases Visual Studio does not save the recently opened solution filter as "recent projects and solutions". Sometimes is does though... and i cannot see when it does happen.

It might help if we understand the logic of find a way to trick VS to save it into the list. As it is very inconvient that developers have to navigate to the solution they are working in daily.

Is there any logic that determines when a (filtered) solution should be added to the Recent solutions list?